# PhpStorm – Prevent array brackets aligning

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm is aligning the brackets from an array.

```
DB::table('something')->create([
                                   'title' => 'John',
                                   'description' => 'Doe',
                               ]); // I don't want to align it this way...


DB::table('something')->create([
    'title' => 'John',
    'description' => 'Doe',
]); // But this way...
```

Where do I change this at `Settings/Preferences > Editor > Code Style > PHP` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally figured this out!

Go to Preferences > Editor > Code Style > PHP > Wrapping and Braces. Uncheck `Align when multiline` under `Function call arguments`.

[image: PhpStorm Preferences Screenshot]

Comment: So thankful I found this. Searched a while for this on my own but didn't associate function call arguments with arrays.

Comment: I can finally be at peace